# Stuck on Grabbing a title from a text file

Tags: c

I am attempting to grab a title from a text file in a way that is completely new to me. My code is set up as follows:

```
struct sequence   
 { char *name; 
   char *sequence;  
   int  sequencelen;
 };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    struct sequence *newseq;
    getsequence("test.txt", newseq);

}


 void getsequence(const char *file, struct sequence *seq)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    struct sequence *seqptr = malloc(sizeof(*seq));
    char c;

    if (!fp)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != "\n")
    {
        if (c == '>')
            continue;

        strcat(seqptr -> name, c);
    }

    printf("Name: %s", seqptr -> name); //Expected output: this_is_a_new_sequence_title
}
```

The structure for the text file is as follows:

```
>this_is_a_new_sequence_title
```

Using structs in this way is, like I said, new to me, but seeing how it is another way to use them I would like to know how to do it. I am unsure, however, if I'm using them correctly, especially with regards to the strcat function.

Do I have to dynamically allocate memory for the struct's member variables, and, if so, how would I go about doing that? Or do I just have everything horribly wrong?

Comment: Did you null terminate the seqptr -> name?

Comment: I did not. How do I go about doing that if I'm reading it from a file?

Comment: There are some issues in your code, fgetc returns char you are comparing it with string literal "\n". Also, strcat concatenates two strings, you are appending a char to it 

>     while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n')  //change

>     char two[]={c, '\0'};
>     strcat(seqptr -> name, two);
you need to allocate memory to your sequence struct elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never allocating memory for the string. So when you call `strcat()`, the destination string is uninitialized memory, leading to undefined behavior.

Also, the 2nd argument to `strcat()` is a string, not a character. That's more undefined behavior as the library function interprets the single character as the address of a string.

You need to initialize storage space for `sequence` when you allocate it. Also, for code like this (dynamic strings) it's good to separate "allocated room" from "string length", and store both.